# Question regarding inductor peak voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, solar-energy

I am trying to modulate an LED to simultaneously power a circuit and communicate with a small solar cell, but I have a question regarding a specific part of the circuit. I have simpified the problem to contain only the part that confuses me, so it is not directly related to my application, but I hope the question is still valid.

In the set-up, I have a solar cell (SM111K10L) illuminated by a modulated LED. The driver controlling the LED is sending a sequence of (10101010....) with frequency from 200 Hz to 2kHz with 100Hz steps, and 2kHz to 30kHz with 1 kHz steps for every fixed x second.
[image]

And then on the receiver side, I run an FFT of the received signal and look at the signal strength (voltage measured across the resistor).
[image]

At this point I would say the result matches what I would expect, as the modulation freuquency increases, I cannot reach the full contrast of the LED (because of the LED/driver I use is not optimized for that), so I see a graduate declination of the signal (voltage) intensity.

Now in my circuit I need to use inductor for some filtering, as my signal frequency is low, I use a very large inductor (100 mH, B82144A2107J000), but there is something puzzling happening with the peak voltage. In order to be able to demontraste the behaviour better, I simplified it to the following

[image]

Everything else is kept the same as the first figure, and only an inductor is added. When I measure the voltages across both the inductor and the resistor and repeat the steps above, I get

[image]

and across the resistor only

[image]

I don't understand why the signal magnitude at around 20 kHz looks like it has been amplified? If I replace the solar cell with a wave generator directly connecting to the inductor and the resistor, I don't observe this behaviour, so it seems to indicate that it's something related to the characteristics of the solar cell. The peak voltage with the inductor is even higher than the measured open circuit voltage at the terminals of the solar cell with no circuit attached. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably due to output capacitance on your solar panel. Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: I have, I don't see anything like that with the transient analysis in ADS - but I don't have the actual parameters so it's a bit of guesswork. Could you elaborate on why the capacitance might have caused this?

Comment: What output capacitance did you have on your solar panel in your equation? I get 633 nF. Sounds high but I don’t know how large your panel is.

Comment: Sorry, I think I am missing why the output capacitance could have caused this. Would you be able to share the circuit/ equation that you use? I tried a few different capacitance values but only up til a few nFs, the solar panel is only 40cm by 43cm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not answer your question, it's more of a comment with a picture.

I don't get nearly as much gain at 20 kHz as you do, but try to get the input waveform as close as the one you have in real life. It could also be something in your LED setup if it's not entirely linear.

40 by 43 cm is a large panel considering the 20 mA peak current limit in your inductor, but your irradiation might be low as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I will see if I could recreate this..

Comment: Just a really quick question if you don't mind - what I saw was that with the inductor the peak voltage is even higher than the open circuit peak voltage - is that also the case here? I didn't understand the mechanism behind that...

Comment: Yes, you will have resonance between C and L, boosting your voltage of sorts. Why is your current so low with such a large panel? Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: Hi Winny, I've resolved this and it was just like what you said - a problem with the capacitor, greatly appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: @user3602697 You are welcome. Please accept my answer if you want to close this question.